# Any modern translations of famous math papers?

Tags: mathematicians, reference-request, translations

I was curious to know if there are any resources similar to [Early Modern Texts](http://www.earlymoderntexts.com/texts)?

What the author of the site has done is taken older and also famous philosophy papers and translated them with more modern terminology. Not necessarily watering down the topic but making it more accessible to contemporary readers. Anyways, I was wondering if there are any such texts like that about mathematics and science.

Also, is there any book or such that collects many math papers in a single volume?

Comment: "Early modern" is a technical term which roughly means 17-18 century. Most important mathematical texts from antiquity to "early modern" have been translated into modern languages, and with modernized notation.

Comment: A single example, not a dedicated volume, is:  MR3331126 
Lie, Sophus
Theory of transformation groups. I.
General properties of continuous transformation groups. A contemporary approach and translation. With the collaboration of Friedrich Engel. Edited and translated from the German and with a foreword by Joël Merker. Springer, Heidelberg, 2015. xvi+643 pp. ISBN: 978-3-662-46210-2; 978-3-662-46211-9

Comment: There are translations of many of Euler's papers on the arXiv (search for author Euler).

Answer (score 1):

Off-hand, I know of three such books. You can probably find more such books by googling their titles and looking for any mention of other books that are like them.

Birkhoff's [**A Source Book in Classical Analysis**](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/toc/0674822455) (1973)

Midonick's [**The Treasury of Mathematics**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000B09U50) (1965)

Smith's [**A Source Book in Mathematics**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486646904) (1929)

Comment: There's also Struik's "A Source Book in Mathematics: 1200-1800" (1986)

Answer (score 1):

There is one book where you can find many remarkable papers by famous mathematicians and their biography too. It is complied by Stephen Hawking and called **God created the integers**. It contains some of the landmark papers in mathematics.